# How to extract jar name and file name in jar from URL in spring cloud?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Recently, I am playing around with Spring Cloud.  And I want to extract the jar name and file name in the jar from a URL.

For example, I have a URL:

```
jar:file:/my/project/directory/target/my-project-0.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/filename.json
```

And I want to get two `String`s

```
/my/project/directory/target/my-project-0.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and

```
/BOOT-INF/classes/filename.json
```

Note that there is no `!` in both `String`s.  How can I accomplish this?

One of the main problems here is that spring will add `!` after `BOOT-INF/classes` and makes a new Jar URL separator.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` with delimiter `!` and then combine the result

```
String s = "jar:file:/my/project/directory/target/my-project-0.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/filename.json";

     String[] arr = s.split("!");
     System.out.println(arr[0]);
     System.out.println(arr[1]+arr[2]);
```

**Output**

```
jar:file:/my/project/directory/target/my-project-0.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
/BOOT-INF/classes/filename.json
```

Or you can also use regex to split the string on `jar!` as delimiter including it, and then replace all `!` with empty string

```
 String s = "jar:file:/my/project/directory/target/my-project-0.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/filename.json";

     String[] arr = s.split("(?<=jar!)");
     System.out.println(arr[0].replaceAll("!", ""));
     System.out.println(arr[1].replaceAll("!", ""));
```

**Output**

```
jar:file:/my/project/directory/target/my-project-0.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
/BOOT-INF/classes/filename.json
```

Comment: It is a good approach.  But I also want to chop off `jar:file:`.  Can you do that?

Comment: update the question with exact output you need @RiversShall